# How to regex specific column of text

Tags: awk, grep

I've been trying to create a regex formula that will allow me to process text only from a specific column from a text file.

Example:

```
John Milanos
Anne Silverwood
Tina Fastman
```

I know that `awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'` will print the desired column and hence allowing me to pipe the text to a second `grep` command. However, my final output will print only the last names. I'd like to print the whole line but only look for patterns in last names.

If I run:

```
awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' listofnames.txt | grep -v 'wood'
```

I will end up with:

```
Milanos    
Fastman
```

My desired output is a list of full names:

```
John Milanos
Tina Fastman
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match regular expressions in awk:

```
awk '$2 !~ /wood/' listofnames.txt
```

`!~` means "does not match".

Comment: Thank you.

While this is very true, what can I do in case I need to run more complex regex stuff ? e.g. find names with 2 or 3 or more consonants. I have the expressions but I can't seem to limit processing to second column only ..

Comment: You can use pretty much any standard ERE regex. The second column is `$2`, to match just use `~`. For instance, to match names with at least 5 consonants, you would use `awk '$2 ~ /([^aeiou][aeiou]*){5}/' listofnames.txt`.

Comment: I am getting close, your example is very good. I am trying to take some egrep commands and they don't seem to work just yet. Testing some more.

Comment: Hi Kevin, will you please show me how to incorporate this command with awk. It's supposed tp grab names with double adjacent chars.

egrep '([a-z])\1.*([a-z])\2'

Many thanks !

Comment: @user3920489 you're now asking a very different question from the one you originally posted. I recommend you accept whichever answer you like for your original question and then post a new question about how to replicate some specific egrep regexps in awk with the relevant sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

with grep:

```
$ echo '
John Milanos
Anne Silverwood
Tina Fastman' | grep -Ev '^\S+\s+\S*wood'

John Milanos
Tina Fastman
```

Comment: This also works, but my problem starts when I need to run special regex stuff... Another way to ask myquestion, is there a way to run grep within awk ?

Comment: `perl` is awk like with more powerful regexs than either grep or awk. Considered that?

Answer (score -1):

What about this regex:

```
\b\S+\s+(.*wood.*)
```

(word-boundary,at least one non-whitespace,at least one whitespace,anything,"wood",anything else)
The braces are there, so you can capture the last name...